# JSF - bean property validation similar to viewParam?

Tags: validation, jsf, properties, viewparams

Is there something similar to `f:viewParam` that can check if a given property is existent, and if not print a message?

For example I have a shopping cart site where the User gets redirected to. The cart resides in session scope.
On a second site a extended cart should be shown where I would like to use this validation.

There are many use cases, for example if a user that would be stored in the session accesses the account site but is not logged in.

Comment: To be sure, you're talking about a property in a session scoped bean? The question and the use case description seem to indicate that, but the title conflicts this. If it was really a view scoped bean property, then it would always be `null` on every fresh new GET request, unless a `<f:viewParam>` is been used.

Comment: Yes i am talking about a session scoped bean. Could also be application scoped. Edited the use case that an extended view of the cart should be shown.